# How is ServletContext created?

Tags: java, jvm

> When the webapp gets loaded the container will create the ServletContext.  There is only one ServletContext per webapp per JVM.
>   The ServletContext object is contained within the ServletConfig object which is provided by the web server upon servlet initialisation.

Therefore:

1. How is ServletContext created by the Container - if it is an interface?
2. If there is only one ServletContext per webapp and that is provided to ServletConfig (of which there is one per Servlet) then doesn't that mean there is one ServletContext per ServletConfig?

<sub>I realize this may seem like a very basic question, but I'm trying to make sure I understand the conceptual aspects involved</sub>

Answer (score 1):

1 - each container has its own implementation, which is internal to the container.  For example, in Jetty, the implementation is [org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.SContext](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.mortbay.jetty/jetty/6.1.0/org/mortbay/jetty/handler/ContextHandler.java#ContextHandler.SContext).

2 - that's the logical conclusion, certainly, but I don't see any reason it needs to be. I would avoid making any assumptions about how many instances of each type of object are created, and just get the appropriate instance through the defined APIs as & when it is required.  It's best not to cache instances of container-created objects, just in case.

Comment: Ok, thanks I never considered the container's implementation.  For my Tomcat it would be ApplicationContext which implements the ServletContext interface.

Comment: As for how it is passed to the ServletConfig, I can only guess at this point that it is passed a reference.  Because it is possible to set and add attributes to the ServletContext at runtime.